# Как отсортировать список в порядке убывания площадей?

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика

> Создайте список, содержащий несколько треугольников. 
>   Треугольник задается в виде кортежа из 3 чисел (длин сторон).
>   Например, [(3, 4, 5), (5, 2, 4), (1, 2, 1)]. Удалите из списка элементы, которые не являются треугольниками. Отсортируйте список в порядке убывания площадей.

```
import math

def triangle(a, b, c):
    if a + b <= c or a + c <= b or b + c <= a:
        return 0

    p = sum([a, b, c])/2
    s = math.sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c))

    return s

input_list = [(3, 4, 5),(6, 8, 10), (2, 1, 1)]
for i in input_list:
if triangle(*i) == 0:
    input_list.remove(i)
```

Как отсортировать список в порядке убывания площадей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import math


def triangle(a, b, c):
    if a + b <= c or a + c <= b or b + c <= a:
        return 0

    p = sum([a, b, c]) / 2
    s = math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c))

    return s


input_list = [(3, 4, 5), (6, 8, 10), (2, 1, 1)]
for i in input_list:
    if triangle(*i) == 0:
        input_list.remove(i)

# вот так будет выглядеть сортировка, выше Ваш код
print(sorted(input_list, key=lambda x: triangle(*x), reverse=True))

# [(6, 8, 10), (3, 4, 5)]
```

Comment: Только reverse нужно сделать ещё, там в порядке убывания.

Comment: input_list = [(3, 4, 5),(6, 8, 10), (4, 4, 4), (3, 8, 10)]  Если ввод такой, то порядок не правильный, потому, что площадь треугольника (4, 4, 4) больше, чем треугольник (3, 4, 5)

Comment: Корень можно не извлекать кстати, и все вычисления тогда в целых числвх можно сделать. (На 2 тоже не делить).

Comment: @pavel, Я код топикстартера не изменял, просто дописал сортировку

Comment: @pavel Что именно вы имеете ввиду? Про корень и деление на двойку

Comment: То и имею. Для сортировки вместо площади можно использовать не S а 16S**2. Это оставляет вас в целом поле и *крайне* полезно. Целые числа не могут при округлении что-то сломать. Особенно в питоне)